# function composition of anytype A

Tags: scala

```scala
def iter[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A = {
  if (n == 1) { 
    f
  } else {
    f(iter(f,n-1))
  }
}
```

I want to make a function `iter` that makes function composition of `f`, for example:

```
iter(f,1) = f
iter(f,2) = f(f)
```

But I can't find a way how to pass type `A` into function `f` recursively, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Also asked in [**scala-users**](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/function-composition/7750).

Answer (score 5):

Note that in your code `f(iter(f,n-1))` where `f` accept an instance of `A` but `iter(f, n-1)` with type `A => A`.

Here is a solution:

```
scala> def iter[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A =
     |   if (n == 0) identity else f.compose(iter(f, n-1))
     |
def iter[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A

scala> iter[Int](x => x + 1, 10)(0)
val res0: Int = 10
```

Or without `compose`:

```
scala> def iter[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A =
     |   if (n == 0) identity else x => iter(f, n-1)(f(x))
```

Or even simple:

```
scala> def iter[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A = Function.chain(Seq.fill(n)(f))
```

Comment: ok I got I missed the type match, but how this can be possible ??
iter(f, n-1)(f(x))??
is this just the library function that scala has? 

Again thank your for your kind reply

Comment: also is 'identity' refers to 'f' function?

Comment: `identity` is defined as `def identity[A](a: A) = a`, it's a function returning its input.

Comment: This was very educational.  I wish I could give it two upvotes.